# What happened to the SEV instruction on the 6502?

Tags: 6502, instruction-set

The 6502 has a group of opcodes which copy bit 5 from the opcode into one of the status flags.

(I know it's not implemented this way, but it looks as though the bit fields are: 2 bits to select the flag out of `CIVD`, one bit to clear or set, followed by 11000).

See:

```
0001 1000   CLC    Clear carry
0011 1000   SEC    Set carry
0101 1000   CLI    Clear interrupt flag
0111 1000   SEI    Set interrupt flag
1001 1000   CLV    Clear overflow flag
1011 1000   TAY    Transfer A to Y
1101 1000   CLD    Clear decimal flag
1111 1000   SED    Set decimal flag
```

The blatant odd one out here is `TAY`, which takes the place of what looks like should be `SEV`. `SEV` does not exist, but intuitively is exactly as useful as `CLV`, and very easy to implement.

On the other hand, the group of instructions `TAY`, `TYA`, `TAX`, `TXA` are not really laid out regularly enough that I see any motive for "overriding" what could've been `SEV`.

What happened?

Comment: The fact that there's a direct pin that can set the overflow flag is definitely a bit of a "i guess someone somewhere had a use case that needed it".  The use of it in the 1540/1541(and I'd guess 1570/1571?) is really fascinating, I don't know if I ever heard of another real-world use of the pin.

Comment: @Joe I suspect that it wasn't "someone already asked for this" but just really good design; I go into more detail [in my answer below](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12539/7208).

Comment: @Joe Having direct testable pins was quite common on CPUs. Many had one or more as part of the flag register, while others had fast implied checks combining pin test and branch.

Comment: a fascinating insight into how the 6502 was put together is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWqBmmPQP40, and the (related) http://www.visual6502.org/ website (you can play with it : http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/index.html) . I would ask those persons that question, if I were you

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**There is simply no need for setting Overflow**. The same is as well true for Negative/Sign and Zero. No operation will be influenced by any of them, it's only used to signal an overflow during `ADC` and `SBC` (well, and `BIT` for testing bit#6).

In fact, **the question is rather, why there is a `CLV`** present, as there is no reason, within the boundaries of the instruction set, to set *or* clear V at all (*1). Any of the three `V` changing instructions will always set/reset it without looking at the former state (*2). Looking at the various transfer instruction it seems rather that `TAY` is out of order.

**The need to add `CLV` becomes obvious** when considering that hardware can set V via the SO (Set Overflow) input pin.

The combination of SO input and the `BVC` instruction creates the shortest possible timing to react for an external signal. Having `BVC` loop on itself will reduce reaction time to a maximum of 3 cycle.

```
L1  BVC  L1
```

Way shorter than any IO test or interrupt handling. In fact, the overhead is zero (compared to more than 13 clocks with an interrupt (*3)) and all response time is reduced to 'instruction jitter' i.e. the time needed before either condition can be detected and the instruction stream is redirected. With an interrupt the actual instruction always needs to finish, which may take anywhere between 1 and 6 cycles. (*4)

Since this can only work as intended if V is cleared before entering the loop, software needs a way to do so. That's why `CLV` got added.

---

###Why `V` was choosen:

The reason why `V` has been used is simply that of the non-modal flags (*5), `C`, `N` and `Z` are changed with next to any data manipulating instruction, while `V` is only influenced by `BIT`, `ADC` and `SBC`. By using `V`, it is still possible to write meaningful programs that check for an external events while doing other tasks, essentially allowing synchronous event detection with the least possible effort.

Any generic IO-Test would require at least a `BIT` instruction (if the bit to test is #6 or #7) and a follow up branch, resulting in at least 5/6 cycles and 4 bytes used. If not placed that nice, it'll needs loading and testing a value, which not only needs more cycles and program bytes, but as well destroys a register as well, serious reducing usefulness. With SO and `BVS` detection can be inserted as often as needed by spending just two bytes and two cycles (in case of not set) each.

---

###Background: Other CPUs

While the V/SO combination is quite restricted and seems more like added on afterthought, having direct testable CPU pins was quite common. Basically two types were used:

- Reflecting the state in one or more Flag bits or
- Offering fast checks, either
- By moving them to flags by a single byte instruction, or
- By offering a combined check and branch instruction for these pins.

In any variation the goal was to allow a few (usually 1..4) input pins to be checked with as least instructions and as fast as possible.

In addition some had as well similar fast output pins.

Some Examples:

- [Intel 8085](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8085) - `RIM`/`SIM` instruction to read SID and control SOD
- [Valvo/Signetics 2650](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signetics_2650) - Two bits (#6/7) in upper status register (PSU) with #6 controlling an output pin (Flag) and #7 reflecting the (Sense) input pin.
- Valvo/Signetics 2650 - As well as direkt I/O instructions (`WRTC`/`WRTD`;`REDC`/`REDD`) for two implied addressed ports (called *C*ommand/*D*ata).
- [Fairchild F-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_F8) - Had two 8 bit ports *on chip* (*6), operated by special short `INS`/`OUTS` instructions.
- [National SC/MP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Semiconductor_SC/MP) - Maxes the Flag-in-Status-Register concept with two input bits (Sense A/B) and 3 output (Flag 0/1/2)
- [RCA/Intersil CDP1802](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_1802) - Offering a single output (Q) set/reset by `SEQ`/`REQ` and four inputs (EF1/2/3/4). The Inputs are not visible in any status register (the 1802 doesn't have one) but direct testable by a separate set of branch instructions (`B1`..`B4`/`BN1`..`BN4`)
- [General Instruments CP1600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) - Maxing out the testable input lines to 16 by having a special branch instruction (`BEXT`- Branch on EXTernal condition) which outputs a 4 bit address on EBCA0..4 and reads the addressed bit via EBCI.

---

*1 - Likewise for `N` and `Z`.

*2 - Unlike the related Carry flag, which needs not only to be checked, but also cleared or set before doing an `ADC` or `SBC`

*3 - 7 for the interrupt itself plus 6 for `RTI` -being an interrupt it as well preservation of registers will usually be needed, weras done via `BVC` (as wait or inline) will already have all registers set as they need to be and no need to restore.

*4 - Not 7, as an instruction only needs to finish when already started :)

*5 - Modal flags are such that change CPU operation, like the Decimal or Interrupt Disable

*6 - No, despite its odd style, it's not a microcontroller

Comment: @Wilson: A fair number of them.  All six read-modify-write functions have variants that also perform an operation on the accumulator, and those variants all support eight-cycle (zp,X) and (zp),y addressing modes.

Comment: @Wilson Bug-using should not be considered part of any game :)

Comment: I wonder how the cost of having a "set overflow" pin compared with what it would have cost to e.g. have all opcodes of the form 00xxxx11 behave as a branch if some particular input was set at the end of an instruction fetch, and 01xxxx11 behave as a branch if that input was clear?  Such a design would have made it practical for a system to support up to sixteen inputs that could be tested and branched upon at a cost of 2-3 cycles per poll rather than 5-7.

Comment: "There is simply no need for setting Overflow" you say, but why was "SEV" present on the Motorola 6800?

Comment: @OmarL Good question, so tell me, why is it? After all, on the 6800 it's even less useful.  It does only make sense as output of an arithmetic instruction (not even BIT). Moreso, it must be tested right after, as a good part of all 6800 instructions manipulate/clear O.  This includes _all_ load and store, making it less useful than on a 6502. This also means it couldn't be used as an auxiliary flag. In contrast with 6500 only ADC, SBC and BIT do manipulate V, which could have enabled the use of V as temporary flag over several instructions (until one of the three comes along).

Answer (score 49):

Setting and clearing carry, the decimal or interrupt flags is useful:

- the carry flag because the 6502 offers only add and subtract *with carry*;
- the decimal flag because it changes the mode of the processor; and
- the interrupt flag because it masks or unmasks the maskable interrupt.

Conversely, explicitly setting and clearing the other flags mostly isn't useful — that's unambiguously true of the negative, zero and break flags. So the more helpful question is: why allow overflow to be cleared, rather than ignoring it completely like negative et al?

The answer is that the 6502 has a specific input pin, SO, which can be used by external hardware to set the overflow flag. The intention is low-latency hardware interfacing — the programmer enters a spin loop like:

```
       CLV
.here: BVC .here
```

The worst-case latency there (assuming no page jump) is three cycles — after two cycles the entire BVC has been read and the decision is made to branch, the overflow flag is set but just too late, an extra cycle is spent performing the branch and then two more rereading the BVC. That's substantially faster than even the fastest IRQ, which starts at 7 cycles.

The main example of usage I'm aware of is the C1540/1541 disk drive where overflow can be enabled to be set each time the flux transition shift register is full.

Comment: It seems in this case it's more the jitter (i.e. window in which the CPU can react) than the lattency (time until CPU reacts) which matters. The jittering is minimzed to 3 cycles instead of at least 7 cycles for other kind of loops involving non-page-zero-memory-mapped IOs, as well as 7 cycles for interupts. If the interupted code is a long chain of NOPs however the jitter is also 2 cycles. Instead of CLV, a WAI instruction would have been preferable, and reduced the jitter to 1 cycle, a.k.a no jitter at all. But that's not what they picked.

Comment: @Bregalad: Having a wide range of eight opcodes that would all behave as "branch if input set" and eight "branch if input clear" would have made it possible for a 6502 system to test up to 8 inputs using single instructions using an 8-input multiplexer with the select inputs tied to three data-bus pins.  I don't know if any processors took such an approach, but the 6502 has a sufficiently large undecoded regions of opcode space that such a thing could have been pretty easy.

Comment: @Bregalad in which case? On the 1540/1541: there are 21 tracks in the densest track. So at least 7,329 GCR-level bytes per rotation, 5 rotations per second. That's *at least* 36,645 events that need to be signalled per second. The 6502 is clocked at 1Mhz. An interrupt call *and return* is the minimum 7 cycles to get into the thing plus the 6 cycles to RTI out again. So you've just spent *at least* 47.6% of your processing budget just on the fact of the IRQ. Conversely if you busy wait on the V flag, you'll spend *at most* 2.2%. So I don't see the jitter argument there. Wrong case, probably?

Comment: @Tommy Erm, as I read his comment, he is point is **in favour** of the SO/BVC solution **because of having a lower jitter than using INT**, which has a 1..6 cycle jitter (he said 7) depending on the instruction during wich execution the interrupt occurs. The main argument is only about the jitter of an interrupt acceptance, not the additional overhead (which makes, as you mention, interrupts even less usable).

Comment: @Raffzahn you are a better reader than I.

Comment: Given a decoded I/O address, adding one chip to a 6502 system will allow it to wait for a signal with *zero* cycles of jitter at no cost beyond the store.  The Atari 2600, which came out in 1977, demonstrates this technique.

Comment: Right, and this is actually an ideal use case for RDY, which blocks on the next read rather than in general. Both Acorn and Atari (in the computers) also used clock stopping to force the 6502 to resume activity only after some other hardware event was finished but I'm pretty sure you're limited to 40µs of a stopped clock on the 6502 as the registers aren't static. I'd need to look that up though.

Comment: @Tommy: The RDY line only affects reads rather than writes, but it can hold the CPU indefinitely.  Clock stopping affects both reads and writes, but its duration is limited.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was probably slightly ambiguous. I don't count RDY as a stopped clock; was trying to contrast with e.g. the Z80 where the registers are static so you can stop the clock indefinitely as long as you're still supplying power. I also strongly suspect this might be different in the CMOS devices having just watched the Ben Eater breadboard 65C02 computer tutorials, as he seems to debug through human clock stepping (_not_ RDY strobing).

Comment: is there a way to get rid of the 3 cycle jitter?

Comment: @RETRAC I know. I didn't ask that. Anyway I got my answer, it IS indeed possible to get rid of jitter (as it happens in demos) it's just a matter of coding in a way that the jitter deletes itself. (If it wasn't true no demo could have stable rasters or anything else)

Comment: @supercat the 65C02 still doesn't have your set of 8 instructions that test and branch on the possible combinations of 7 input pins, but it does have [a set of 8](http://6502.org/tutorials/65c02opcodes.html#4) that test and branch on each of the individual bits in a ZP byte.

Comment: @MarkReed: Unless I/O is mapped into the first 256 bytes of address space, the BBR and BBS instructions are useless for I/O synchronization since they're limited to zero-page addressing mode.  If one adds hardware to disable RAM for four zero-page addresses and generate an active-low chip select for a 4x2 multiplexer, one could test and branch on any of eight inputs using "BIT $xx / Bxx " instructions just as fast as one could use BBx for that purpose.

Answer (score 10):

Here are a few further thoughts on the setting of flags and the `SO`
(set overflow) pin mentioned in the other answers, in response to
[Joe's comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12536/what-happened-to-sev#comment39386_12536),

> The fact that there's a direct pin that can set the overflow flag is
>   definitely a bit of a "i guess someone somewhere had a use case that
>   needed it". The use of it in the 1540/1541(and I'd guess 1570/1571?)
>   is really fascinating, I don't know if I ever heard of another
>   real-world use of the pin.

I wouldn't be surprised if there were no specific use case at the time
and this were just another example of Chuck Peddle's great design
skills.

Fast response to external signals was clearly a design goal of
the 6502. Note, for example, how unlike the 6800 it stacks only the
minimum number of registers when responding to an IRQ. (The 6809 later
copied this with its additional "Fast IRQ.") And then there was the
BIT instruction, setting not one but two¹ flags directly from memory
(read: I/O ports), and various other instructions that directly
twiddled memory without needing to touch registers, also saving cycles
when doing I/O.

But one thing that Peddle needed was to be able to compete with the
6800's WAI instruction, which basically "pre-executed" the initial
part of the interrupt response (immediately stacking the registers and
loading the PC with the address in the IRQ vector) and waited for the
interrupt, allowing it to start executing the interrupt code with no
latency.

I don't know how expensive that would have been to implement (the 6502
was, if anything, even more focused on being cheap than fast), but
that technique also had a major issue: once the response was complete,
there was significant time until the next response could be generated
because the CPU would still have to go through the whole RTI/WAI or
RTI/INT sequence before the interrupt code could be executed again.
Peddle's solution avoided this by not using an interrupt at all but
instead a spin loop. This increased the latency in response to the
external signal by up to three cycles, but meant that when processing
of the signal was completed, one could be ready to respond to the next
instance of that signal *much* faster than the 6800 could, increasing
the maximum signal frequency that the 6502 could handle.

Setting flags to branch based on the state of a chip pin was not a
technique original to Peddle; the [RCA COSMAC 1801
processor](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_rcacosmacR_3918911), released in early 1975 as the 6502 design was
being worked on, had "four I/O flag inputs directly testable by branch
instructions." (You can see more about how this works on the
[RCA 1802](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_1802#Registers_and_I/O), which was basically just a single-chip version of the
two-package 1801.)

---

¹<sub>The N (negative) and V (overflow) flags are copied directly from
bits 7 and 6 of the memory location tested. Additionally, the Z (zero)
flag is also updated based on the AND of the A register and the memory
value; this may or may not be useful and/or a time saver depending on
what's currently in the A register at the time you do the test.</sub>

Comment: The 6502 could have processed I/O much more effectively if opcodes of the form xxxxx111 were NOP, xxxx0011 were "branch if input low", and xxxx0011 were "branch if input high".  Adding a 74HC138 and some 8-bit addressable latches and 8-bit multiplexers would have made it easy to interface to up to 32 inputs or outputs with very fast I/O instructions.

Comment: "there was the BIT instruction, setting not one but two flags directly from memory" -- actually up to THREE flags. bit7 of memory goes to N, bit6 to V, and still the result of ANDing A with memory sets Z.

Comment: @lvd Thanks for pointing that out! I've updated the answer with a footnote about this. However, the Z flag doesn't really fall under what I was trying to communicate with "direct" in that it needs other setup, and possibly register saving or unwanted register value destrcution, to set the test value.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Some nitpicking on the footnote: Overflow is noted as V thruout all 6500 documentation.

Comment: @Raffzahn Good nitpick: I have fixed the post. Thanks. Now, of course, I have a nitpick with the MOS for calling the pin `SO` instead of `SV`....

Comment: Well ... maybe because it's a pin and thus hardware ... hardware always was a different world than software :)

Comment: The 6502-based ECD (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECD_Corporation) MicroMind set the overflow bit on a bus timeout. If you gave the video state machine priority, bus timeouts were frequent when accessing video memory, but it was just one extra instruction to retry. Or, you could give the CPU priority and live with the screen glitches...